# "Full acces"s vs "only web access" to a network

Tags: network-design

I'm having trouble with some of the wording used by my lecturer on a exercise he gave us. The goal of the exercise is to design a network for three "labs" in our University:

1. A general purpose lab with full access to the University network
2. A lab that only has web access to the main University network and
   the internet
3. A lab which should only have web access but no access to the main
   University network

I don't understand the difference between "full access to the University network" in 1. and "only web access to the main University network" in 2. as we never encountered this distinction during the lectures.

Comment: If I got down-voted because this question is too noobish, I understand. However I did search both SE:serverfault and Google and couldn't find an answer. I would welcome at least a comment explaining the downvote.

Comment: full access would be everything including services like FTP & SSH, all ports and protocols.  Web only implies only HTTP and HTTPS (ports 80 and 443 on TCP) access.

Comment: Why don't you ask your professor for clarification? This may help them realise their course isn't as clear as they think too.

Answer (score 4):

I think this problem is more suited to Superuser then Serverfault, but Web only access implies access only to Web type services, typically associated with ports 80, 443 and (for DNS lookups) 53.

Full access to the Uni network could include things not served through a web server, for example FTP, SSH, SNMP and custom services run on the LAN.